# JAAS + JSF 2.0 + Glassfish

Tags: jsf, authentication, glassfish, jaas

I'm not sure how to integrate those three.

What I have is a simple jsf login page and I have also created JDBCRealm.
I have simple Data access layer which connects using jdbc to database.
I have restricted the access to the other pages than login which works quite fine.

```
  <login-config>
<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
<realm-name>JDBCRealm</realm-name>
 <form-login-config> 
    <form-login-page>/index.jsf</form-login-page> 
    <form-error-page>/xxx.jsf</form-error-page> 
</form-login-config> 
</login-config>

 <security-constraint>
<web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Secure Pages</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
    <http-method>POST</http-method>
</web-resource-collection>
<auth-constraint>
    <role-name>Users</role-name>
</auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

What should I do to actually make it work, because I couldn't find proper solution:
Is it like that?
- do I need to validate if password and login is correct in my beans under login page ? Or is it done automatically by glassfish in this JDBCRealm? If so, how to enable/forward it there?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the page associated with `<form-login-page>` you need to create a form which look *at least* like this with exactly the URL `j_security_check` and input field names `j_username` and `j_password`:

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="j_username" />
    <input type="password" name="j_password" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The container will then intercept on it and handle it fully transparently.

If you want to have all freedom to use JSF components instead, then you need to let it take the control over the login as well in a managed bean action method:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();

try {
    request.login(username, password);
    return "home";
} catch (ServletException e) {
    errorMessage = e.getMessage();
    return "error";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I get 404 with "The requested resource () is not available.". In address bar i have then : http://(remoteaddress):8080/PresentationL/j_security_check

Comment: I'm sorry, It totally works - I just forgot to have incorrect_password site xxx.jsf - thats why I get 404... Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Code for the **Login Page** :

## Login Form

```
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">

        <h:outputLabel for ="uname" value="Enter User Name :  "/>
        <h:inputText id="uname" value="#{JSFManagedBean.username}"/>
        <h:outputLabel for ="pass" value="Enter Password  :"/>
        <h:inputSecret id="pass" value="#{JSFManagedBean.password}"/>
        <h:outputText/><h:outputText/>
        <h:outputText/>
        <h:commandButton id="login" value="Login" action="#{JSFManagedBean.Login()}"/>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
```

Code for Managed Bean :

```
Managed Bean contain the following Login Method 
    public String Login() {
        try {
            message="";
            HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
            request.login(username, password);
            if(request.isUserInRole("Admin"))
                return "/AdminPage/Admin.xhtml";
            else if(request.isUserInRole("Visitor"))
                return "/VisitorPage/Visitor.xhtml";
            else {
                message= "Either Login or Password is wrong";
                return "/index.xhtml";
            }

        } catch(Exception e) {
            message= "Either Login or Password is wrong";
        }
        return null;
    }
```